# Shard a collection in mongo atlas

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, sharding, data-partitioning

Is it possible to Shard a collection in MongoDB atlas? I tried to Shard a collection but when going to enable sharding to my database it gave this error.

```
MongoServerError: (Unauthorized) not authorized on admin to execute command { enableSharding: "xapi", lsid: { id: {4 [5 97 193 191 78 207 71 39 186 1 57 136 181 234 80 85]} }, $clusterTime: { clusterTime: {1661827468 9}, signature: { hash: {0 [239 144 235 226 101 40 124 83 122 213 201 45 199 157 206 184 76 44 96 38]}, keyId: 7103402705267195904.000000 } }, $db: "admin" }
```

I am using MongoDB free tier (M0). and already allow permission to enable sharding. I attach the image

permission

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/ says:

> You can't deploy a M0 free cluster or M2/M5 shared cluster as a Sharded Cluster.